# Are USB flash drives less susceptible to catastrophic failure than a micro-sd card in raspberry pi 3B+?

Tags: memory, ssd, memory-card

Raspberry Pi users have indicated SD cards will eventually fail from wear when booted in the rPi3B+.

I understand that writing to the SD card will eventually cause a failure.  SSDs delay this process by engaging "wear-leveling" techniques. It is unclear if agood (Sandisk) USB boot flash drive engages wear-leveling.

Would a USB memory stick suffer the same failure mode as an SD card is is it somehow less prone to a catastrophic failure than a micros SD card, when used to host Raspbian in an rPi3?

In my mind, I am trying to figure out of the order of good=>better=best is:

- SD-Card => USB-memory-stick => SATA-SSD  OR
- [SD-Card = USB-memory-stick] => SATA-SSD

Comment: Since different brands/models have different failure rates, you need to compare the expected lifetime of the models you are interested in.

Comment: Maybe you need to add magnetic disks also. Because all above are flash memory based and have limited number of write cycles